# Cannot initialize podfile in my XCode project

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to initialize a podfile in my XCode project so that I can import Firebase, but when I run `pod init` I get the following error:

/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/bin/pod init
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.3.1
        Ruby : jruby 9.1.7.0 (2.3.1) 2017-01-11 68056ae Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14 on 1.8.0_92-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
    RubyGems : 2.6.8
        Host : Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G17023)
       Xcode : 8.2.1 (8C1002)
         Git : git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 18ffe9708184f46d875a2e7e50bddcc085f8d490`

#### Plugins

`cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`

#### Error

`` NameError - uninitialized constant Nanaimo::Reader::StringScanner
Did you mean?  Nanaimo::Reader::StringScanner
               StringScanner
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3344:in `const_missing'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0@global/gems/nanaimo-0.2.3/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:96:in `initialize'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.3/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:27:in `read_from_path'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.3/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:200:in `initialize_from_file'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.3/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0@global/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:979:in `load'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/bin/pod:1:in `<eval>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1000:in `eval'
/Users/andrewmcgovern/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' ``

Please let me know if you have an answer to this or know of another, better way to import Firebase.